# Persistent animation with kineticjs and tweens

Tags: javascript, animation, kineticjs

I have a "periodic" animation defined by a sequence of tweens in kineticjs. I would like the animation to repeat forever with the page being still responsive to other events. Which is the best way to do it? Is defining a function that calls itself a good strategy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a series of `Kinetic.Tween` with the use of the `onFinish` property, like this:

```
    var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
        node: hexagon,
        duration: 1,
        x: 50,
        y: 250,
        onFinish: function () {
            var tween2 = new Kinetic.Tween({
                node: hexagon,
                duration: 1,
                x: 550,
                y: 250,
                onFinish: function () {
                    var tween3 = new Kinetic.Tween({
                        node: hexagon,
                        duration: 1,
                        x: 300,
                        y: 400,
                        onFinish: function () {
                            //Tween back to original position so it looks like we're in a loop
                            var tween4 = new Kinetic.Tween({
                                node: hexagon,
                                duration: 1,
                                x: 50,
                                y: 250,
                                onFinish: function () {
                                    tween.play();
                                }
                            });
                            tween4.play();
                        }
                    });
                    tween3.play();
                }
            });
            tween2.play();
        }
    });

    tween.play();
```

In the last tween, you want to play the original tween `onFinish` so that it creates the infinite loop.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/TtfJA/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function with [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) calling itself or use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) only once.